# Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not position within a table (informix.tblName)

Tags: sql, jdbc, informix, sqlexception

> Query: my_table is a **view** not a table

```
static final String query= 
    "SELECT "+MailboxId+", " + 
    Action+", " + 
    ActionType+", " + 
    MsgType+", " + 
    Priority+", " + 
    MsgID+", " + 
    MsgCountsSequenceNumber+", " + 
    MsgCounts+", " + 
    TimeOfEvent+"  " + 
    "FROM my_table " + 
    "ORDER BY TimeOfEvent;";

public ResultSet executeQuery(Statement st, String query) throws SQLException
{
    boolean isDeadlock= false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int retries= deadlockRetries;
    do {
        try {
            rs = st.execute(query); //here it produces exception 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (e.getErrorCode() == SQLERR_DEADLOCK) {
                diag_log(LOG, "Deadlock exception generated during execute query=", sqlQuery, ".  Retries=", Integer.toString(retries));
                isDeadlock= true;
                synchronized(_lock) {
                    deadlockCount++;
                }
            }
            else {
                diag_log(LOG, "SQL Exception: ", Integer.toString(e.getErrorCode()), " query=", sqlQuery, " exception= ", e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "unavailable"); // this log gets printed
                throw e;
            }
        }       

    } while (isDeadlock && retries-- > 0);
    return rs;
}
```

Logs:

> Failed to read database Mydyndb with query SELECT MailboxId, Action, ActionType, MsgType, Priority, MsgID, MsgCountsSequenceNumber, MsgCounts, TimeOfEvent FROM my_table ORDER BY TimeOfEvent;. TECHNICAL DETAILS: **Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not position within a table** (informix.my_table).

Need to know the reason for this exception

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create your statement and also the query string?

Comment: You get this exception when there is a lock on the table.

Comment: @Copilot : DO you get it when there is a row level lock on the table or there is page/table level lock?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the **ISAM Error**, use `e.getCause()` to get it. This will pinpoint the problem.

One common problem is locking, your log shows the `tblName` table but the statement showed is:

```
SELECT 
    MailboxId, 
    Action, 
    ActionType, 
    MsgType, 
    Priority, 
    MsgID, 
    MsgCountsSequenceNumber, 
    MsgCounts, 
    TimeOfEvent, 
    CallerANI, 
    Sender, 
    SenderDisplayName, 
    Uid, 
    ObjectId 
FROM 
    my_table 
ORDER BY TimeOfEvent;
```

Is `my_table` a view over `tblName` or is it something wrong with your log?

If the statement is correct, and it is not a view, you're doing a full scan. There is not much to do except:

1. Check if you're using [lock wait](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_422.htm), if not used it, if so try to
   increase.
2. Check the [isolation level](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1161.htm?lang=en) you're using when issuing this
   statement.

If it is a view, check if you're filtering some field over `tblName`.

If you're, check the presence of **INDEX** over it and if the distribution is correct. Check the [level of isolation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0113.htm%23ids_sqs_0113?lang=en) set on the table

If you're not, check the possibility to create one.

If no filtering is involved, we got another full scan.

Comment: Sorry I did that mistake (table name) while writing the post and i forgot to mention that its a view not a table.

Comment: Can you use `e.getCause()` to get the **ISAM Error**? Can you update your question with the **DDL** of the view?